# C# Simples - Forms - Passar para o datagrid o que eu seleciono no combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, datagridview

Galera, Boa tarde, eu sou novo em linguagem de programação, preciso de uma ajuda. Eu to conseguindo chamar os dados do banco no combobox com o select, mas não to conseguindo fazer uma função que quando eu clique em OK, ele me mostre a resposta do que eu selecionei. Preciso dessa ajuda.

```
using System;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Instanciando conexao e comand do SQL
        SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection("Password=xxxxxxxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxxxInitial Catalog=BD_Testes;Data Source=xx.xxx.xx.xx");
        SqlCommand comand = null;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = null;

        //Dataset é uma tabela em memoria
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();


        //Abrindo conexao com o banco
        sql.Open();

        //Defino o comando que será executado
        comand = new SqlCommand();
        comand.CommandText = "select ccNomeFisicoArquivo FROM tbArquivoImportado";
        comand.Connection = sql;

        //Instancio o adapter, passando comand como parametro.
        //O resultado do select será atribuido ao adapter, que irá preencher o dataset com o resultado
        //Dataset é uma tabela que fica na memoria.
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comand);
        adapter.Fill(ds);

        //Para cada linha da tabela no dataset, preencho o combobox
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {

            comboBox1.Items.Add(row["ccNomeFisicoArquivo"]);

        }

        //Sempre fechar a conexao
        sql.Close();
    }


    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }



    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<int> listaDosIdsNaGrid = new List<int>();

        //AQUI EU PASSO P GRID O ITEM DA COMBO
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(comboBox1.SelectedText);
        listaDosIdsNaGrid.Add((int)comboBox1.SelectedValue);



    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }



    }
}
```

---

O combobox ta funfando, eu preciso pegar o item do combobox e quando eu clicar "OK" ele aparecer o resultado do select que eu der no item

Comment: Aparecer o resultado onde? Acho que é isso que não ficou claro.

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, pelo que entendi você que pegar o texto selecionado no Combobox esse seria o selecteditem

veja um exemplo:

```
private void showSelectedButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    int selectedIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
    Object selectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem;

    MessageBox.Show("Selected Item Text: " + selectedItem.ToString() + "\n" +
                    "Index: " + selectedIndex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bem não entendi muito bem, mas acho que você quer o conteúdo do datagrid no textbox e isso? se for. coloque a seguinte linha no evento duplo clik ou no clik no datagrid.

```
string strSelect;
// vamos obter a célula atual (que possui o foco)
DataGridViewCell celulaAtual = dgvProcurar.CurrentCell;
// vamos exibir o valor da célula atual
string valor = celulaAtual.Value.ToString();
strSelect = "SELECT campos FROM tabela WHERE campo LIKE '" + valor + "' ORDER BY campo";.
//agora buscamos as informações na tabela do banco
DataTable tabela;
tabela = conexao.ExecultarSelect(_sql);
if ((tabela == null) || (tabela.Rows.Count == 0))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Registros não encontrados", "Título", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
else
{
    textboc.Text = tabela.Rows[0]["Campo"].ToString();
    //Assim por diante
}
```

Comment: Bom, vou tentar explicar melhor...

Com esse código, eu jogo no combobox, o que eu tenho no banco de dados... Tudo que eu tenho no ccNomeFisicoArquivo, ele joga no combobox.
//Para cada linha da tabela no dataset, preencho o combobox
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {

            comboBox1.Items.Add(row["ccNomeFisicoArquivo"]);

        }

Eu seleciono um desses nomes que está no combobox, quando eu selecionar, vou apertar "OK", e ele tem que me trazer os valores da linha do banco em que esse nome está...

Comment: Consegui jogar no Datagrid... o jeito do Geilton ajudou, mas como eu sou noob, eu coloquei de outra forma pra entender melhor...   DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Index");
            dt.Columns.Add("Nome do Arquivo");
            dt.Columns.Add("Item 3");

            DataRow dr;

            dr = dt.NewRow();

            dr[0] = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
            dr[1] = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
           // dr[2] = 

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;